# Am I at risk by storing or using software that violates copyright?

Tags: copyright, software, open-source-software

Imagine the following scenario:

A software company copies code from some open source project and includes it in their own software without giving credit to the original authors, violating the open source license and copyright.

The software company then gives me the software and its source code under a proprietary license. If I am not aware of the copyright violation, am I at risk of legal consequences if I store the source code on my computer and use the software?

Suppose that at some point I become aware of the copyright violation. Am I at risk at this point?

Comment: Realistically, open source copyright holders will not pursue you if you act in good faith. They might ask you to comply with the license in some way. There are not a lot of open source copyright trolls. (I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice)

Comment: You might want to look at the Waymo vs. Uber case for inspiration.  Otto was a self-driving car company that was bought out by Uber for ~$1B.  Waymo (a google spinoff working on self-driving cars) proved that Otto was using a massive amount of code an executive stole while working at Google and Waymo for a decade.  The executive ended up pleading to criminal charges over the theft and spent 18 months in prison.  Uber settled a lawsuit with Waymo for ~$250M over the stolen code.

Answer (score 10):

### If you copy copyrighted material without permission or another exemption, you are at risk

It doesn’t matter if you know the material is subject to copyright, it doesn’t matter if you think you have permission but don’t, it doesn’t even matter if you knowingly make the copy or if it is some background process you don’t know about. Copyright law is really simple: if you make an unlawful copy, you broke it.

If this seems unduly harsh, remember you are dealing with a law with its roots in the 18th century that was internationalised at the beginning of the 20th century. Making copies then was a hard, deliberate process - you couldn’t “accidentally” or “inadvertently” make a copy of a literary or artistic work. Now you can - the world has changed, the law hasn’t.

Comment: But it was the software company that made the copy and gave it to them (perhaps by sending them a disk), not the OP. This is more analogous to "possession of stolen goods", isn't it? You may have to destroy your copy, but you're not liable for primary infringement, are you?

Comment: Is there any precedent on this? Is copyright infringement a statutory crime? Don't you have to have mens rea?

Comment: Ahh so civil copyright claims are statutory, though punishment seems to depend on willfulness, Criminal copyright infringement on the hand is not statutory and the government must prove mens rea.

Comment: That distinction (civil vs. criminal) might be worth explaining in the answer, given the differing stakes and also likelihood of prosecution/suit.

Comment: This answer is probably overly scary (which makes it a good lawyer answer, but not necessarily good practical advice). As a party who purchased and is using the software, it's very unlikely that you are **making copies** of it. On a purely mechanical level as part of use, some transient copies - likely in small parts at a time and rarely or never the whole thing - might be made, but if/when that happens, it's being done by a machine that was programmed to do so by someone else, not OP the operator, ...

Comment: ...and it is exceedingly unlikely that anyone, especially an open source software author, is going to find a lawyer and a court willing to entertain the idea that someone else's automated processes, making transient partial copies of a work the OP had good faith reason to believe they had acquired legally, is actionable copyright infringement by the OP.

Comment: @R..GitHub: Those copies are exempt under [17 USC 117](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/117)(a)(1) under US law. I don't know whether other countries have analogous laws, but I imagine it is likely.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the citation.

Comment: This does not answer the question as stated. OP asks about "using" and "storing". That is, a company gave him a copy of some software, that he thought was a legal copy, but it turns out to be an illegal copy for some reason (maybe it includes 'copyleft' open source software that requires releasing specific source code, which was not done, for example). The question is, what is the legal risk or problem of retaining that illegal copy on one's hard disk ('storing'), and what is the legal risk or problem of running that illegal copy that was already copied onto one's hard disk ('using').

Comment: @Brandin copyright doesn’t care about storing or using, it cares about copying (the hint is in the name). If you can get a copy on your computer without copying it, that’s fine. But you can’t.

Comment: In the specific scenario presented in this question, it seems to me that that a software publishing company is the one that did the copying, not the OP himself. It's quite possible to get and store software (from someone else) without doing any act of copying yourself, nor causing an act of copying to be done, for example, if the software is stored on a medium of some sort, such as a CD, a USB key, etc.

Comment: @Brandin are you suggesting the developer broke into the OPs house and copied it from their device/website to the OP’s computer

Comment: Personally I still have lots of software that is simply sitting on media like CDs, etc.  I don't think simply having ('storing') those media on my shelves is itself a copyright violation, even if it turns out that something on there was a copyright violation at some point. Maybe whoever originally put the copies of illegally copied material on those media violated copyright, for example.  Of course, if I install a copy that is illegal on my computer, that's a different situation that was not made clear in this Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned open source software: If I give you some open source software in a way that makes it copyright infringement, then using the software is in principle copyright infringement. However, the copyright owner is likely more concerned with ensuring everyone’s right to use the open source software, so they are not going to sue you as long as you agree to the license terms.

Comment: I don't see how 'using' the software (i.e. double clicking on an icon to run it) is a legal problem for copyright. If the company gave you a copy of some software without abiding by the license (e.g. without giving you the source code, in the case of GPL code), then the company were the ones who violated copyright by giving you that copy (while ignoring the license). But once it's on your hard disk, I don't see how any further copyright violations could occur, even if you run it. Unless you then give that copy to someone else, of course; at that point, you violate the license again.

Comment: You launch an application, it gets COPIED into memory.

Comment: I believe that sort of transient, internal copying that occurs as an essential part of a computer operation has been ruled or specified to be an exceptional case (i.e. it's not a copyright violation).